# LibGdx ProgressBar knob margin?

Tags: java, libgdx

Im trying to do a progress bar, the knob and the background are nine-patched. and I get this knob margin at the right and left

ScreenShot: [ProgressBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMQ3P.png)

I know its because the background and knob are nine-patched, i tested it. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

heres the code

```
ProgressBarStyle    pbStyle = new ProgressBarStyle(guiSkin.getDrawable("background"),guiSkin.getDrawable("knob"));
pbStyle.knobBefore  = pbStyle.knob;
pb                  = new ProgressBar(0, 100, 1, false, pbStyle);
pb.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 10);
pb.setPosition(0, pb.getHeight() * 2);
stage.addActor(pb);
pb.setValue(100);
```

ScrennShot 9-patch: [image]

Comment: My knob starts at the beginning and ends at the end. So either you have some code messing up elsewhere or your region might have whitespace in it.

Comment: did you 9-patched it with libGdx draw 9-patch? My background and knob are exatly the same, only difference is color, so if i had a whitespace, both would had the whitespace and both will start in the same position.

Comment: oh and it works fine without the 9-patch, then I draw the 9-patch and wont work as expected.

Comment: Are you sure you are not adding whitespace to the ninepatch?

Comment: I dont think so, I added a screen shot, so you can see

Comment: You progress bar is round and your ninepatch is square. Whats up with that? Havent used ninepatches for a while though, usually use the split parameter in the atlas for it.

Comment: Yes that's another one i did, to see if the square one works, but it didnt work either... I patched the circle one the same way.

Comment: Well, I'm doing exactly the same but I use TextureRegionDrawables and they fill the whole bar. just run this code and pass in the table where you want it in.

http://pastebin.com/JfhGxF8K

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution by adding this code:

```
//for the knobBefore
pbStyle.knobBefore.setLeftWidth(0);
pbStyle.knobBefore.setRightWidth(0);

//for the background
pbStyle.background.setLeftWidth(0);
pbStyle.background.setRightWidth(0);
```

In the case of **vertical progressBar** use `.setBottomHeight()` and `.setTopHeight();`

I hope this helps!